# Power BI - you have exceeded the amount of embed token

Tags: powerbi

We have been using Power BI dashboards in production embedded in web application for a long time. Suddenly it stopped working in application but in Power BI Cloud the reports are working.

Debugging the code, we are getting the following error.

> you have exceeded the amount of embed token that can be generated on a shared or proplus capacity. you need to purchase azure capacities to generate embed tokens. see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=868976

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Well, as the message tells: Purchase azure capacity..

Answer (score 3):

Using Pro accounts without a dedicated capacity, or Premium Per User accounts, is not allowed in production scenarios. In this case, the number of embed tokens that can be generated is limited. You ran out of tokens and you must purchase [Power BI Embedded (A SKUs)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/) or [Power BI Premium (EM or P SKUs)](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/).

> **[Development testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/move-to-production#development-testing)**
>
> For development testing, you can use embed trial tokens with a Pro license. To embed in a production environment, use a capacity.
>
> The number of embed trial tokens a Power BI service principal or master user (master account) can generate, is limited. Use the [Available Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/available-features/available-features-get-available-features) API to check the percentage of your current embedded usage. The usage amount is displayed per service principal or master account.
>
> If you run out of embed tokens while testing, you need to purchase a Power BI Embedded or Premium capacity. There's no limit to the number of embed tokens you can generate with a capacity.

Comment: Andrey, Thanks for your response.

We changed from Power BI pro Embedded A1 capacity to A2 capacity in Power BI Pro, Is this what we need to do?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/

After changing the capacity also it's throwing the same error

Comment: A1 SKU is enough. If you get this error, then the workspace where the report/dataset resides is not attached to the capacity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Power BI report or dashboard in your web application

1. Using Azure AD application
2. Using power BI user credential

if you using 1st approach (Use Azure AD application to retrieve Power BI embed token) then you will receive the sudden error

> {"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"You have exceeded the
> amount of embed token that can be generated on a shared or ProPlus
> capacity. You need to purchase Azure capacities to generate embed
> tokens. See [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=868976"}}](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=868976%22%7D%7D)

**The permanent solution is**, you have to purchase Azure capacities to generate embed tokens. it makes more than $700 (Suitable for production)

**The temporary solution is**, you can create a new Azure AD application and assign the required permission to that application as you did for your existing Azure AD application (Suitable for a Development environment)