# Power bi embed capacity

Tags: asp.net, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We have been using Power BI dashboards for development testing to embedded in web application(.net) for a long time. Suddenly it stopped working in application but in Power BI Cloud the reports are working.

Debugging the code, we are getting the following error

This is the error

[image: This is the error snip]

1.I have checked this embed content in apps, it is already enabled

[image: Tenant Settings]
2.Embed Url is also present in the code with proper report id and dataset id, Url is not getting any error but report is also not shown in the browser.
3.We are using pro licensing that gives free embed capacity.

Comment: What capacity type are you using? Pro doesn't give free embedded capacity, it allows you to use a user in development, then you have to switch to a capacity for production.

Comment: This might be the issue if you don't have a capacity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68389963/power-bi-you-have-exceeded-the-amount-of-embed-token?rq=1

Comment: This is for development testing, and i think In development testing, we can use free embed trial tokens with a Pro license.

Comment: You use the phase 'in production' and edited the question to remove it. It looks like you have run out of tokens as 'you have been using it for a long time'. I suggest you raise a ticket with MS to investigate what tokens you have left, or try it with a capacity